# PHPExcel - How can i change color, border and background of chart using phpexcel library?

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am working with PHPExcel library, I am not able to change the color of the graph.

let me know if anyone have a solution to it?

Check in this screen I want to change colors which are blue, red and green:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel graph design (border, graph color, graph inner position)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612897/phpexcel-graph-design-border-graph-color-graph-inner-position)

Answer (score 3):

The current release of PHPExcel does not support to do so.

Take a loot at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612897/phpexcel-graph-design-border-graph-color-graph-inner-position#19396447http://), there are a few workarounds mentioned.